# How can I save edited .html page from my iFrame to server in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I am developing rich text editor which edits scripts (.html files) located on server.
Currently, I have an iframe with enabled designMode in javascript so I can type in embeded .html document. Later, I will add buttons for text editing and inserting images. The problem is, I don't know how to save those changes and override existing .html file in wwwroot folder.

[Link to the project on github](https://github.com/ivkovicstefan/Doctrina-web)

Only idea is needed, you don't need to provide me the exact code.